# CSS rule based on content

Tags: css

I would like to apply a different style to all anchors containing a specific word. Can it be done in pure CSS? It's ok if it's CSS3-only.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No. `:contains` was once proposed but is not in the current Working Draft of CSS3 Selectors.

You would need some JavaScript, for example:

```js
Array.from(document.links).forEach(link => {
  if (/\bSpecificWord\b/i.test(link.innerHTML)) {
    link.style.color = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#">SpecificWord</a>
<a href="#">OtherWords</a>
```

Comment: I really hope they have fixed this issue by now. It seemings glaringly obvious that styling an element by the words in its contents is an extremely common problem.

Answer (score 23):

You can [match attribute values though](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings). If you use custom data attributes, it might get what you want.

Comment: This answer works just fine in chrome. `td[data-carrier="Verizon"] { color: #F00; }` Results in `td` cells with the `data-carrier` attribute of value `Verizon` giving them the color of `Red`.

Comment: This would be the same as creating a separate CSS class name for each content value, ex. '.carrier-verizon {color:red}'

Answer (score 6):

yes there is a `:contains` selector in CSS3.

```
li:contains("special"){text-style: italic;}
```

it is mentioned about 1/2 down this page [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/18/css3-selectors.html?page=2)

This is [something you can also do with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/contains#text) too ...

Comment: Interesting, but it's only for static media "This selector is for static media only (i.e., print and not screen display)."

Comment: ah yes i didn't catch that nuance .. i can see why it makes sense however (maybe) . thanks for spotting that

Comment: The `:contains` selector didn't made it into the later specifications.

Comment: It works, I don't believe it! Thanks!

Comment: Does not work on Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox v55.x

Comment: this works if i edit the css  in devtools and add it,but @screen it is ignored

Answer (score 3):

@bobince help me and I wrote this code:

```js
var tableCells = document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
for (var index = tableCells.length; index-- > 0;)
    if (tableCells[index].innerHTML == 'closed')
        tableCells[index].parentNode.style.background = '#FEE';
```

If the content of some TD is '**closed**' then the background color of the TR will be identified with light red color.

Comment: I don't think accessing a nodeList via bracket notation is standard.

Answer (score -4):

Use the [Hitch](http://www.hitchjs.com/) which is a tiny JS library. You can easily apply content based style to any element. It has lots of options and great for conditional styling.

Comment: Hitch is a dead link, has it moved?