# Convert True/False to Tick/Cross image using CSS only

Tags: css

I have some data that I'm reading from JSON and writing into a Table.

Currently looks like following.

```
<table>
<tr><td>Feature 1</td><td>true</td><td>false</td></tr>
<tr><td>Feature 2</td><td>false</td><td>false</td></tr>
<tr><td>Feature 3</td><td>true</td><td>true</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is leave the true/false data as it is but use CSS to turn the data into Tick/Cross or smiley / frown images.

I thing I have seen CSS3 notation for this, but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with pure CSS since it can't select an element by its content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1777373/1540570

Comment: don't use :contains() - it is removed from the CSS3 spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can you id manipulate the HTML a bit and add classes to the TD's with the values true/false.

```
    <tr><td>Feature 1</td><td class="true">true</td><td class="false">false</td></tr>
```

In the CSS you can use the attribute selector or in this class just the class selector

```
td.true {

}

td.false {

}
```

You might also be able to hide the text with the text-indent property.  Alternatively you can just output the true/false as a class rather than HTML text in the cell.

Comment: you can shorten it by using `td.true` (it's a good idea to add a prefix, so the class name becomes like `td_true`)

Comment: yes what was I thinking.  I was just thinking about adding attributes to TD that I forgot I was using a class and it can just use a class selector lol