# Showing English and Gujarati text on the same page | Font issue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have an application, where the text is in English and Gujarati language. The English and Gujarati text is there on the same page. like:

```
Name/નામ
```

Now the problem is that if I have Verdana or some other font in the body tag applied through css, the font is applied on the Gujarati text as well and the text is sometimes not visible correctly, as my application uses absolute positioning (and the texts are in some div).

If i use `shruti` font, then English text is not displayed correctly.

Applying Verdana in `Name` and shruti in `નામ` is not feasible as I will have to change my application a lot for that.

Please let me know a alternative/solution.

Comment: Don't use absolute positioning

Comment: @Morpheus: Sadly, that is not an option that i have :(, even if i don't use it, the text would still not be visible properly.

Comment: show your html code how you using `font-family` and css also

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to surround your Gujarati content with a `span` which has a language-specific class  assigned to it.

```
<span class="gujarati">...</span>
```

You can then set the CSS so that `Verdana` is applied to all elements but the elements with the `gujarati` class name.

```
body { font-family: Verdana; }
.gujarati { font-family: shruti; }
```

This way you do not have to modify all your content, just the Gujarati part.

Comment: Currently i have just single label, which contains english and gujarati. I will have to separate out each such label which will be a tedious task.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be useful but check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content

Comment: No, not useful, as the texts in Gujarati are not small in number.

Comment: Then I don't see any other way to specifically target the text other than what I've already mentioned. Please update this thread if you do find an alternative solution.