# CSS only when certain text between tags

Tags: css

Let's say I have this html:

```
<p class="test">foo</p>

<p class="test">bar</p>
```

Is there a way I can make it only select the first line. So the css would be something along the lines of

```
.test:(text="foo") {

}
```

but only using css?

Edit: Sadly it cannot be done with pure css.

thanks anyways

Comment: `.test:first-line { color: red; }`?

Comment: how about `:first-child` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content)

Comment: can't be done with pure CSS if you want it to be based on a specific string

Answer (score 1):

If you have **multiple** elements:

```
<p class="test">foo</p>
<p class="test">bar</p>
<p class="test">zed</p>
```

and want to select the **first** one, then you can use `:first-child` selector:

```
.test:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

[image]

- You can check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcLhv/).

---

If you have **one** element:

```
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, quis, expedita, illo adipisci voluptates minus labore ex quos aspernatur impedit rerum nam! Officiis quas nam fugiat illum maiores repellat voluptas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, quis, expedita, illo adipisci voluptates minus labore ex quos aspernatur impedit rerum nam! Officiis quas nam fugiat illum maiores repellat voluptas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, quis, expedita, illo adipisci voluptates minus labore ex quos aspernatur impedit rerum nam! Officiis quas nam fugiat illum maiores repellat voluptas.</p>
```

and want to select the **first line**, then you can use `:first-line` selector:

```
.test:first-line {
    color: red;
}
```

[image]

- You can check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jcLhv/1/).

---

If you want to select your element, based on the **content** within it, it not possible by CSS, you must javascript for it, for example jQuery has one implementation:

```
<div>John Resig</div>
<div>George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div>J. Ohn</div>

<script>
    $("div:contains('John')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>
```

- [`:contains()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score -1):

****EDIT: Question-asker doesn't want first-child, and instead wants it to be based on a string, which you cannot do with pure CSS. The following answer is for first-child implementation ****

This answer is for first-child:

If it's only ever going to be the first one you need the :first-child pseudo-element.

There is also last-child and nth child, but :First-child is the one that's safe to use in IE8 and earlier, but you have to have a doctype:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/firstchild.html

What you'd need to do is something like this:

```
p:first-child {
    /* CSS Styles */
}
```

**Here is a fiddle with it working**:

http://jsfiddle.net/shayl/KwWjt/

Comment: I don't want it to be based on first child, I want it to be based on what's between the tags

Comment: you can't do that with CSS, sorry. You'll need javascript to search a specific string like that.