# Apply css only when text is equal to X

Tags: css

I have a link like this:

```
<h1>
    <a href="#">Title 001 - Stuff</a>
</h1>
```

I want to style only "Title 001". It's possible to create a css rule to do this?
I don't remember how I did in the past, I think it was something like this:

```
h1 a[text="Title 001"]
```

But this doesn't work

And... then I want to know if it possible to do that with "Title XXX" where XXX is a dynamic number.

Comment: No...CSS cannot detect content.

Comment: No you cannot style text, you can only style elements, wrap the text in an element then style the element.

Comment: You would need to do this with JavaScript and apply CSS

Comment: How are you making this HTML?  Why not just add a class to the `<a>` tag?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Duplicate Content in Attribute

If you would like to avoid using JavaScript, you could duplicate the content (gasp) in an actual attribute, and select based on that attribute:

```html
<a href="#" data-content="Title 001 - Stuff">Title 001 - Stuff</a>
```

And then select anything that starts with "Title":

```css
a[data-content^="Title"] {
    color: red;
}
```

### Manually Test textContent

Alternatively, you'd have to take an approach with JavaScript:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll( "a" );
var pattern = /^Title\s\d{3}/;

for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    if ( pattern.test( links[ i ].textContent ) ) {
        links[ i ].classList.add( "distinguish" );
    }
}
```

This is simply one example of how you could add a `.distinguish` class to all matching elements.

### Filtering with jQuery

If you are using jQuery (or a similar utility) you could accomplish this without so much verbosity:

```js
$("a").filter(function () {
    return /^Title/.test( $(this).text() );
}).addClass("distinguish");
```

### Isolating "Title :digits:"

If you only want to isolate, and style, the `Title XXX` portion and you don't have access to the source templates, you could do this too with JavaScript:

```js
$("a").html(function ( index, html ) {
    return html.replace(/(Title \d+)/, "<span>$1</span>");
});
```

The above assumes you are using jQuery, but if you're not you can accomplish the same thing with the following:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a")
  , length = anchors.length
  , el;

while ( length-- ) {
    el = anchors[ length ];
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(Title \d+)/, "<span>$1</span>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @jonathan-sampson works great, but I would only apply style "Title XXX" text, not the whole text. I'm thinking isn't possible without another surround tag like <span>. But isn't possible because the text comes from a cms, I can't change the text and I don't want to use Javascript.

Comment: @singuerinc You're correct that you will need to wrap that text in a new element. If you do not have access to the source, you can wrap it with JavaScript too.

Answer (score 5):

You can't select by content, but you can use [attributes](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) (as you nearly did already).

```
<h1>
    <a href="#" data-content="Title 001 - Stuff">Title 001 - Stuff</a>
</h1>
```

```
a[data-content="Title 0001 - Stuff"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With css

```
<a href="#" data-content="Title 001 - Stuff">Title 001 - Stuff</a>
a[data-content^="Title"] {
    color: red;
}.
```

But

Here is what you can do with `jQuery` in much smarter way,

```
$('a').filter(function (i, element) {
    return element.text == "Title 001 - Stuff";
}).css('color','green');
```

### [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XjX9L/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is impossible in CSS.

You're using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
a[text="Title 001"]
```

and your `<a>` hasn't got an attribute called `text`.

You would have to use Javascript to handle such situation. There was once an idea to have a `:contains()` pseudo-selector but this has never been implemented.