# Change style of an element which contains a specified word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change style of an element which contains a specified word in href.

jquery

```
jQuery('a:contains("afyon")').css('color': '#fff');
```

html

```
<div class="saglink"><a title="bayan adana" href="http://www.site.co/adana-bayan/">Adana bayan</a></div>
<div class="saglink"><a title="bayan adiyaman" href="http://www.site.co/adiyaman-bayan/">Adıyaman bayan</a></div>
<div class="saglink"><a title="bayan afyon" href="http://www.site.co/afyon-bayan/">Afyon bayan</a></div>
<div class="saglink"><a title="bayan aksaray" href="http://www.site.co/aksaray-bayan/">Aksaray bayan</a></div>
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and return all elements whose `href` value contains a specific word. You should also convert the string to lower case in order to get all possible matches.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0xL9m24z/)

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prop('href').toLowerCase().indexOf('afyon') > -1;
}).css('color', '#fff');
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use **[attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**:

```
jQuery('a[href*=afyon]').css('color', '#fff');
```