# Access class with specific text content and display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a large Joomla CMS Website I'm working on.

**Problem:** I need to hide a menu tab globally across the entire site. The menu item I need to have does not have a unique ID or class; but instead shares the same class as the other tabs I need to keep on the page. 70% of the tab I need to remove shows in 4th order so I started with the below.

```
.tabs:nth-of-type(4)
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

But! Seeing as how the rest is in different order, this wont work. The tab in question I need to remove looks like the below across the mark-up.

Update: This is what I currently have via the suggestions below but it isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.djaccTitle:contains("Location").css( "display: none;" )')
});
<span class="tabs">Location</span>
```

**Is there a way to write an if statement or similar lightweight solution that can sniff out text content within the class, so if it says Location, then hide?**

I would like to find a solution like this, as opposed to going through 1000 files of mark-up removing manually. Cheers for any pointers

Update: This is what I have via the current suggestions below but it isn't working!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs:contains("Location").css( "display: none;" )')
});
```

Comment: i would use js to add classes/ids to every tab, then you can style away in css without issue. use positional identifiers; digging into content via :contains will be slow and buggy because parents ":contain" the same text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery [:contains() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) should work. I think you have an error in [.css() function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) syntax.

Please try with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( '.tabs:contains("Location")' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe what you are asking for exists with pure CSS at this time.

What I would do is use jQuery's `:contains()` selector:

```
$('span.tabs:contains("Location")')
```

or even better:

```
$('#idOfTabsContainer span.tabs:contains("Location")')
```

And of course, don't forget to put this in a `document.ready` to ensure that your DOM element has been loaded successfully:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#idOfTabsContainer span.tabs:contains("Location")')
});
```

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me; should a certain jQuery be used / not used?

Comment: You will need to put this in a document.ready callback (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a `:contains` selector that they were going to add to CSS.

But alas, you may have to resort to some JS, [as addressed already here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content)

jQuery's got your back though:

`$('.tabs:contains("Location")')`

Answer (score -1):

> Problem: I need to hide a menu tab globally across the entire site.

Solution 1: Disable the menu item. Boom, it is gone from your menus, site wide.

Solution 2: Hide the menu item with css by adding a unique class to the menu item itself and then hiding it with css.

[image]

```
.hide-me-with-css {display: none;}
```