# Change color of href links based on their domain names in css

Tags: css, colors

I would like to give different color to different external links using just CSS.

For example, we have few external links:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>
<a href="http://example.edu">home page</a>
```

I want to give different colors to links based on their domain names(.edu, .org, .com etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS rule based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content)

Comment: Note that the 'domain names' are 'stackoverflow.com' and 'example,edu' what you're referring to is the 'TLD' (top level domain), the 'com' and 'edu' part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `attr` selector like this:

```css
a[href$=".com"] {
  color: red;
}
a[href$=".edu"] {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> 
<a href="http://example.edu">home page</a>
```

---

In this case we can use `$` as filter:

> **[attr$=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose last value is suffixed by "value".

[You can use more combinations to evaluate the attribute you want](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)