# What's the easiest way to format web-based data by content, CSS, Javascript, or other method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have this HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <title>IN Print ALL</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="\\MyServer\Webcaster\favicon.ico" />
<style type='text/css'>
    caption
    {
        background-color:333BFF;
        color:white;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:336699;
        text-align:center;
    }

    table
        {
        font-family:Tahoma;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        font-size:15pt;
        width:85%;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:white;
        border-width:1px;
    }

    th
    {
        font-size:10pt;
        color:black;
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(odd)
    {
  background: #eee;
    }

    tr
    {
    }

    td
    {
        font-size:10pt;
        color:black;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:cccccc;
        text-align:left;
        padding:3px;
    }

</style>
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
    </head>
    <tbody>
<table align="center">
 <caption> On The Floor Printing IN ALL as of {%Current Date Time%}
        </caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Cycle Code</th>
   <th>Product</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>Warehouse</th>
   <th>Production Due Date</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Status Comment</th>
   <th>Sales Order Number</th>
   <th>Job Description</th>
   <th>Ship Expire Date</th>
   <th>Days Until Due</th>
   <th>Total Hours</th>
   <th>Remaining Sch Hrs</th>
   <th>Sch Hrs</th>
   <th>Rev Budget Hrs</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
  {BEGIN*REPEAT}
  <tr> 
   <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
   <td>{Product}</td>
   <td>{Description}</td>
   <td>{WarehouseCode}</td>
   <td>{ProductionDueDate}</td>
   <td>{StatusCode}</td>
   <td>{CurrentStatusComment}</td>
   <td>{SalesOrderNo}</td>
   <td>{UDF_JOBDESC}</td>
   <td>{ShipExpireDate}</td>
   <td>{daystilldue}</td>
   <td>{TotalHours}</td>
   <td>{RemainingScheduledHours}</td>
   <td>{ScheduledHours}</td>
   <td>{RevisedBudgetHours}</td>
  </tr>
  {END*REPEAT}
 </tbody>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

It creates a nice table that displays the data. What I'm wanting is for any record that has a {daystilldue} < 1 to display in a red font. I've been looking at a JavaScript IF statement, but I haven't been able to get it to work. I'd appreciate any ideas or incites on the best way to do this.

Comment: Presumably you're using some sort of templating system?  What sort of logic does it support, if any - that'd be the first place to look to do this.  CSS itself [isn't able to do content based rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content).

Comment: @James Thorpe We're exporting the data out of Knowledge Sync. I'll investigate if it has any type of logic built in for formatting. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for a pure JS answer wherein the style is changed directly, but probably the best way(referring to separation of concerns) would involve adding a class to your styling called(as an example) `font-red` and then apply that class with JS. Unless there's a particular reason you don't want to go that route?

Comment: Can you confirm what precisely `{daystilldue}` will contain - ie would "I want to make it red when it's either 0 or prefixed with -" (as in -1, -2 etc) be accurate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having thought a bit further, you can actually do this with a small modification to your HTML - using data attributes, and a selector looking for the right thing.  In this case, it looks for a value of `"0"` or anything starting with `"-"`, ie negative numbers.  In the example below I've cut down the table to just a few columns and added a few rows to show how the template might expand in certain scenarios.

I've put an inner span in this `td`, as altering the `color` of a `td` also affects its borders.

```css
span[data-daystilldue="0"], /* anything that's 0 */
span[data-daystilldue^="-"] { /* or anything starting with -, ie negative numbers */
  color:red;
}

table {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 15pt;
  width: 85%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
}

td {
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: cccccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Cycle Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Days Until Due</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {BEGIN*REPEAT}
    <tr>
      <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
      <td>{Product}</td>
      <td><span data-daystilldue="{daystilldue}">{daystilldue}</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
      <td>Example 1</td>
      <td><span data-daystilldue="1">1</span></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
      <td>Example 2</td>
      <td><span data-daystilldue="0">0</span></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
      <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
      <td>Example 3</td>
      <td><span data-daystilldue="-1">-1</span></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
      <td>{UDF_CYCLE}</td>
      <td>Example 4</td>
      <td><span data-daystilldue="-20">-20</span></td>
    </tr>
    {END*REPEAT}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'll try to incorporate this today, it looks easy enough. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Lonnie Great!  I see you're new to Stack Overflow, it's worth taking a look through the [tour] page to see how it's different to the usual forum model.  If you feel my answer has helped you out - you can tick the checkmark next to the voting buttons - you'll get your first bit of reputation from doing so too!