# Apply CSS style only if the content of pseudo element is "\1F551"

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm working on a page, where the content of some pseudo elements are added via JavaScript.

Now I have to use CSS to style only those pseudo elements, that have "\1F551" as content.

Is it possible to apply CSS styling rules to a pseudo element only if its content is equal to "\1F551"?

Comment: In short: No, CSS does not help you here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777357/css-rule-based-on-content

Comment: Sorry, but the link to duplicate question isn't the same as my question. I'm taking about the content of a pseudo element like this: a::after { content: "\1F551" };